# FileNotFoundError when using os.rename() in Python

Tags: python, datetime, error-handling, operating-system

I'm following this [post](https://datatofish.com/rename-file-python/) to rename the file name, but I got error below, I've tried lots of potential solutions I can find here but none of solves my issue:

```
import os
import datetime

current_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
current_date

os.rename(r'C:\Users\...\xxxx.csv', r'C:\Users\...\xxxx_' + str(current_date) + '.csv'
```

The Error is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\...\\xxx.csv -> 'C:\\Users\\...\\xxx_2020-04-14 16:43:56.csv'
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please provide the full path on the code and also a picture containing the path existence, other wise we would not be able to really help you out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't Seem to like the format of current_date

```
import os
import datetime

current_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


old = 'C://path//somefile.csv'
new = 'C://path//somefile'+'new.csv' #str(current_date)+'.csv'
os.rename(old,new)
```

This worked for me (windows), You can't use certain characters in filenames, in this case it's the ":" thats causing problems, changing it to '-' should solve it.

Comment: Hi can you explain more how I append the current datetime to the file with your method? If I use ```new = 'C://path//somefile' + str(current_date) + '.csv'``` it will return error again.

Comment: change: current_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  to current_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')  , note your changing the colon after H and M to a dash, if your using a mac or linux system you need to change all the // to \\.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the file really doesnt exist in your path.. use `os.walk` to check if the file inside the folder, just like this:

```
for _ in os.walk(path):
 print(_)
```

Comment: I edited the post. try to run the code now and check wether you find the file your trying to rename in the path you type in the os.rename()

Comment: got another error ```SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape``` I suspect it's because there are several numbers (userID) in the path

Comment: try to change the paths to this: `path = os.path.join("c:", os.sep, "Users", "someone", "Desktop", "folder1", "csv_file1.csv")`

Comment: I just printed out the file, the csv file is in this path, this is the output: ```('/Users/.../test', ['.ipynb_checkpoints'], ['test1.csv', 'Untitled.ipynb'])
('/Users/.../test\\.ipynb_checkpoints', [], [])```

Comment: The full path is 'C:\Users\Uxxxxxx\Downloads\test\test1.csv'